# Creating ZIP archive on fly from PHPExcel Objects

Tags: php, web, zip, phpexcel

I'm developing small API in PHP and I need to create a ZIP archive on fly but the contents (files) are also created on fly with the PHPExcel library, anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Easiest way is to create a temp dir, create your excel files and dump them in it, create a zip archive of the contents of the dir, serve the zip archive then delete the temp data. This is the programmatically easiest way, but it is not very efficient in terms of disk I/O - so you could do it all in memory, but this is not so efficient in terms of memory usage. Either way, all you need to do is split the process into the stages of `Create Excel Files` -> `Zip them up` -> `Send the data` -> `Remove any temp data you created during 1 and 2`

Comment: I have to do it only on fly, I can't use I/O operations in that case

Comment: Do you mean you have to do it in memory and can't write anything, even temporarily, to disk? This will be very expensive in memory...

Comment: Now it's working in that way I have an API which is using PHPExcel to create PHPExcel object after success it's pushing the file to user, I'm not storing anything as temp.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can do this:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'file content goes here');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'ok';
} else {
  echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

So you have to get the content from PHPExcel in a string an use `addFromString` method.

For more information have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Comment: So you man that in ma case I should use something like that:    <?php
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
   $res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
   if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFromString('test.xls', $objectWriter->save("excel_file.xls"));
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
   } else {
    echo 'failed';
   }
   ?>

Comment: You need to get a string vom PHPExcel object and path this string to `addFromString` method. I do not know if such method exists. Check the manual of PHPExcel. Otherwise you have to go the way described by DaveRandom (Create Tmp XLS File ...).